# How would I go about searching for a string of words across multiple lines

Tags: java, parsing, input, io, bufferedreader

This is a homework assignment I am working on which required me to read data from a file and the parse through it finding the line number and starting index of certain key phrases or names. The file is being hosted online so I've decided to use the URL class to pull in data rather than download the file locally if that makes a difference here.

I have no problem pulling in the data, reading it, finding the line numbers, column numbers, and sorting it. What I'm getting hung up on is when the data spans across two lines. Currently I am reading line by line using BufferedReader and parsing each line individually but this excludes any instances where a phrase is broken up with a newline/carriage return. I was thinking perhaps I should just read all the data into a String so I can parse through it looking for instances where a newline may be breaking up my words.

Not sure if this is the proper way to approach this issue. How else could I do this?

Edit: The data set is textual content embedded within a  element. No \n or \r seems to exist at the end of any line.

Edit: Not looking for code. Just a few extra brains to help me think about this differently.

Edit: Perhaps not the best way to go about this... we are early in the summer session of this DS/Algo course so efficiency isn't being tested yet. I grabbed the last word of my current line and ran a hasNext() operation to `peak` at the next line. We are only working with two word names otherwise a heavier RegEx solution would have been warranted.

Thanks for the feedback everyone.

Comment: What do you have to return? Is your job only to return a `boolean`, signaling whether the pattern is within the text? If so, you can use your approach. If this is not possible, i would implement the search manually, skipping all newline characters in the search-text.

Comment: The output is a .txt file that lists the line number, column number, and the text that I was searching for. Order of occurrence must be retained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that either you:

1. Normalize your key phrases and names (represent `"word\nplus\nword"` as "line *n* has *word*, line *n+1* has *plus*, line *n+2* has *word*")
2. Process newlines as part of the matching characters (process byte by byte instead of line by line)

From your current strategy, option 1 would be easier as you could keep a list of those *things* that need to be matched and feed each *thing* with the line to see if it still matches or should start over. Something like

```
in <- get url <input url>
results <- empty list
phrases <- process phrases <input phrases>
while in has line
  line <- next line from in
  for each phrase in phrases
    send line to phrase
    state <- state of phrase
    if state is found then
      add phrase result to results
```

Obviously this means the representation of each phrase would be stateful and an active part of the process, that is, responsible for processing each line and dealing in any internal state required for multi-line matching.

Comment: This is definitely something I have considered. It looks like I'll likely have to read the text into a file and append the \n characters on myself so I can make this happen.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could try with Regex. [This](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) is a link to what it is.

It's basically a search engine that allows you to use an "expression/algorithm" to specify what your searching for.

An example to suit your need might be:

```
"phrase[\n ]*?is[\n ]*?a[\n ]*?test"
```

matches both occurances in:

```
This is a test. The phrase
is a test. This is a test
the phrase is a test.
```

the `[\n ]*?` part means it will match if the phrase contains a new line or not

It is there three times for the three possibilities it might be (between words)

----------------------------------Edit.------------------------------

You can always try your regex with [regexpal](http://regexpal.com/).

Comment: Regex is what I see most queries return regarding this type of question. I've been somewhat evasive to using it, not because I don't understand RegEx but rather, the context in which I am reading data throws me off a bit. I'll probably have to revise my approach here and not just look at individual lines as this obviously is preventing me from matching instances where data runs over two lines.

Answer (score 0):

If the search can span multiple lines, then you don't have lines - you have a single String (with embedded newline chars). Approach the problem with this in mind and a simple solution (without giving you code) would involve first using regex to find the phrase, after replacing all whitespace in the phrase with `\s+` and using that as the regex. If you get a hit, look at all the test preceding the hit: the number of newlines is your line number, and the number of characters after the last newline is your column.

Comment: I need to update my original question as this was something I was trying to figure out as well. The text is embedded within a <pre> element and actually has no newline/carriage return characters as far as I can tell.